# Count from multiple fields in a record

Tags: database, ms-access

Put simply, I have the following data set as part of a row in MSACCESS. I am trying to create a calculated field that will count columns with median of 2, another calculated field for median of 3 etc . Any help?

```
No1.Median  No2.Median  No3.Median  No4.Median  No5.Median  No6.Median
3                  4            4            2           3       3
```

Comment: First, normalize your data with a UNION query.

Answer (score 0):

No way I can think of that's pretty...  You would have to create a query, add all your fields to it, and then add this at the end:

```
Med2: IIF([No1.Median] = 2, 1, 0) + IIF([No2.Median] = 2, 1, 0) + 
      IIF([No3.Median] = 2, 1, 0) + IIF([No4.Median] = 2, 1, 0) + 
      IIF([No5.Median] = 2, 1, 0) + IIF([No6.Median] = 2, 1, 0)
```

Then add another field like this:

```
Med3: IIF([No1.Median] = 3, 1, 0) + IIF([No2.Median] = 3, 1, 0) + 
      IIF([No3.Median] = 3, 1, 0) + IIF([No4.Median] = 3, 1, 0) + 
      IIF([No5.Median] = 3, 1, 0) + IIF([No6.Median] = 3, 1, 0)
```

And do the same for all the others.  It's ugly, but short of pivoting and then re-pivoting it's the only way I can think of doing it.

That's assuming those values are Integers.  If they're text, you have to wrap them in quotes (like, IIF([No1.Median] = "3", 1, 0) etc...)